# Preserving character sequences like <- or != in Xaringan, preventing substitution

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I am building a Xaringan deck for a short course on R.  I need students to learn the character sequences for assignment `<-` and relational operators like `!=`.

However, knitting to slides replaces several character sequences with more elegant display characters.  For example, `<-` becomes a left-pointing arrow (←).

Can I preserve the original characters in slide output?

I still get the replacement inside single backticks (`) for code formatting and even inside R code chunks (```).  Escaping the characters with \ does not help.

```r
---
# Two ways to save variables to memory

R has two ways to assign variables: `=` and `<-`.  

The following expressions are equivalent:

`turnout_rate = .598` and `turnout_rate <- .598`
```

When knit to slides, all `<-` above are replaced with a left arrow (←) . I would like to keep the original characters `<-`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This does not happen for me. Maybe you have a font like [Fire Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) installed where `<-` is rendered as a ligature. You can test this by using `Right Click -> Inspect Element` in the preview/browser. Which font is used for code segments?

Comment: Thank you @RalfStubner - that was it.  I am using the Metropolis theme which uses Fira Sans in ordinary text and (apparently) Fira Code for code.  I installed [Fira Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Mono?selection.family=Fira+Mono), which does not impose ligatures and added the following to my custom CSS: `.remark-code  { font-family: 'Fira Mono'; }`. This fixed my problem.  LMK if you want to add an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Previous comment incomplete. To get the inline code too, you need the following in the custom CSS: `.remark-inline-code { font-family: 'Fira Mono'; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a CSS style sheet in place that calls for a font like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) where `<-` is rendered as a ligature. You can test this by using `Right Click -> Inspect Element` in the preview/browser.

You can change the used font via some custom CSS code, e.g.:

```css
.remark-code, .remark-inline-code {
    font-family: 'Fira Mono', 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
```

You have to specify the custom CSS file in the YAML header, e.g. for the `default` theme and a file named `custom.css`:

```
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "custom.css"]
---
```

References:

- https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Changing-fonts
- https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Prerequisites